# How to get detailed informations about a layer (SRID, extent, ...) in Geoserver REST API?

Tags: geoserver, layers, extents, srid, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying go get detailed informations about a layer using the Geoserver REST API (I'm using Geoserver 2.8.1), but according to the online API documentation, I can only get basic informations such as the name and the styles.

Are these the only informations I can get using the REST API, or is there any way to get more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeoServer REST api is for the management of the server and is not really designed for queries about the data layers. You should use the WMS getCapabilities request for that information.